# Edit xml File and save it from c#

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have an xml file which contain images url . i am verifying the url whether url is responsive or not. If url is not responsive then i am removing that url from xml. and saving all changes . but i am getting error like

> 'The process cannot access the file 'E:\1.xml' because it is being used by another process'

```
xmlTR = new XmlTextReader(@"E:\1.xml"); 
PrimaryXmlDoc.Load(xmlTR);   
foreach (XmlNode node in PrimaryXmlDoc.SelectNodes("/fp-hotel/Images/Url"))
       {
           if (CheckUrlExists(node.InnerText))
           {
           }
           else
           {
               XmlElement _xmlElement = PrimaryXmlDoc.DocumentElement;
               node.ParentNode.RemoveChild(node);
           }
       }  
PrimaryXmlDoc.Save(@"E:\1.xml");
```

Comment: Do you get the error while opening or saving the xml?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have to Close `XmlTextReader` before using it second time. If you don't do that, the previous instance will keep your file open and you won't be able to open it again.

EDIT: And that's what happens here is probably that you want to save file before closing it.
Add line:

```
xmlTR.Close();
```

before

```
PrimaryXmlDoc.Save(@"E:\1.xml");
```